# JNI doesn't work on AppKit Thread

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-native-interface

I'm calling a native function from my Swing application on Mac. The call comes from **AWT-EventQueue-0** thread. I call some async native API and end up in a callback in the **AppKit Thread** (`[NSThread isMainThread] == TRUE`). The problem is JNI doesn't work on AppKit thread. For example, call to env->FindClass cases a SIGABRT that crashes my app. However, JNI works correctly in the EventQueue thread.

How can I execute native callback code inside **AWT-EventQueue-0** thread or make JNI work inside **AppKit Thread**?

OpenJDK 1.7, OS X 10.10, XCode 6.1.1

Comment: Full stack trace please and an example of code (runnable if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help as it's hard to know exactly what's going on without more information, but I've run into this problem when I store an env pointer in one thread, and then use that pointer in another.  The different threads need their own env pointers.